# Please some advanced users can help me?

Tags: magento-1.7, database, event-observer

Ok this is getting really serious here. I will continue explaining the code first.

This is my WSDL path connection:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx', array("connection_timeout"=>120));
```

These are some of my classes not all of them:

```
$aWebOrder = new WebOrder;
$aWebOrder->OrderNumber                         = $order->getIncrementId();
$aWebOrder->OrderCreationDate                   = $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$aWebOrder->CustomerAddress = new CustomerAddress;
$aWebOrder->CustomerAddress->FirstName          = $order->getCustomerFirstname(); 
$aWebOrder->CustomerAddress->LastName           = $order->getCustomerLastname();
$aWebOrder->CustomerAddress->Telephone          = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
$aWebOrder->CustomerAddress->Fax                = $order->getBillingAddress()->getFax(); 
$aWebOrder->CustomerAddress->Email              = $order->getCustomerEmail();
```

This is the code where i want to pass my product info:

```
$aProduct = new OrderDetail; 
$aProduct->SkuId =     $order->getSku();
$aProduct->Quantity=   $order->getQtyOrdered();
$aProduct->Sellprice = $order->getPrice();

$aProduct = new OrderDetail; 
$aProduct1->SkuId =     $order->getSku();
$aProduct1->Quantity=   $order->getQtyOrdered();
$aProduct1->Sellprice = $order->getPrice();

$aWebOrder->ProductDetailList = array($aProduct,$aProduct1);
```

And this is the code which pass these classes to the wsdl file and after they are sent into a database:

```
$params = array('OrderWebAPILogin' => array("login" => 'xxx', "password"=> 'xxxx'), 'DbVersion' => 16, 'Order' => $aWebOrder,'RequestOptions' => NULL);
$result = $client->addOrder($params);
```

This way the code works just fine. because i haven't created a foreach in the product section.

In the product section i add this code to get all products info with a foreach

Here is the code i use:

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){

$aProduct = new OrderDetail;

$data[] = array(

    $aProduct->SkuId        => $item->getSku(),
    $aProduct->Quantity     => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
    $aProduct->Sellprice    => $item->getPrice()

    );
}

foreach($data as $product){

    $aWebOrder->ProductDetailList = $product;

}
```

I don't get any error on the log file but no data are inserted into database, it means that i am doing something wrong when i pass the values into the foreach or into the $params array().

This is an event observer which fires anytime an order is completed and purchased.

Comment: which event are you using? can we see your Observer class?

Comment: Please write a proper title

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand you code but I see a difference between the case that works and the one that doesn't.
In the first case (when it works) I see that `$aWebOrder->ProductDetailList` is an array of objects with type `OrderDetail`.
In the second case (when it doesn't work) `$aWebOrder->ProductDetailList` is an array of strings.
In this last case the `$product` var will look like this:

```
array(

    $aProduct->SkuId        => $item->getSku(),
    $aProduct->Quantity     => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
    $aProduct->Sellprice    => $item->getPrice()

)
```

If `$aProduct` is an empty instance of `OrderDetail` then `$aProduct->SkuId` will evaluate to `null` and so will the rest of the values.
So your array will end up something like this:

```
array(
    null => '44.99' // or some other price
)
```

I assume that this is not the format you were expecting.